# bootstrap popover/tooltip syntax

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

Can someone please explain what this line of jquery means in tooltip(used by popover)

```
inside = /in/.test(placement)
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

What does this mean/for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regex test, which checks to see if the string "in" is in `placement`. It seems a bit wasteful here, though...

Comment: please explain how it is wasteful

Comment: @River wasteful in my opinion because placement is either top(default), bottom, left or right. i can't see why bother looking for 'in'

Comment: @River Wasteful because it uses a regex instead of a simple `indexOf`.